# How to retrieve last user log in with MSAL

Tags: azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I am trying to get when the user's last log in with MSAL.

So for example if a user was last logged in say 12/12/23 11:22, when a user logs back in a week later, it will show there last log in (session) was on 12/12/23 11:22am.

I haven't been able to find any specific documentation on the MSAL docs, and was wondering if I might've missed something. Alternatively, I would need to create a database, which'll log every login of a user, which seems a bit overcomplicated and I don't think I can store that sort of user data.

Any guidance would be great, thanks.